# How to read multiple times from same io.Reader

Tags: go, reader

I want to use `request.Body(type io.ReadCloser)` which is containing a image.

I dont want to use `ioutil.ReadAll()` as i want to write this body directly to the file as well as want to decode it, so i only want to use the reference to the content to pass to further function calls,

I tried creating multiple instances of reader for example shown below

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "strings"
)


func main() {
    r := strings.NewReader("some io.Reader stream to be read\n")
    a := &r
    b := &r
    log.Println(ioutil.ReadAll(*a))
    log.Println(ioutil.ReadAll(*b))

}
```

but in second call it always results into `nil`.

Please help me how can i pass multiple separate reference for the same reader?

Comment: Undoable the way you asked for. Use a `io.TeeReader` to capture what you read for further reference, e.g. in a `bytes.Buffer`.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

[`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) is treated like a stream. Because of this you cannot read it twice. Imagine an incoming TCP connection - you cannot rewind what's coming in.

But you can use the [`io.TeeReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#TeeReader) to duplicate the stream:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    r := strings.NewReader("some io.Reader stream to be read\n")
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    tee := io.TeeReader(r, &buf)

    log.Println(ioutil.ReadAll(tee))
    log.Println(ioutil.ReadAll(&buf)) 
}
```

Example on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/c1P6i85dLX)

**Edit:** As @mrclx pointed out: You need to read from the `TeeReader` first, otherwise the buffer will be empty.

Comment: Also, if the stream's data will be large - say `1GB` - don't use `ReadAll`. Instead - and since the OP wants to write it first to a file - use `err, _ := io.Copy(fh, tee)`

Answer (score 13):

When you read from ioutil.ReadAll(r) then, the content is gone. You can’t read from it a second time.
For an example:

```
var response *http.Response

//Read the content
rawBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }

// Restore the io.ReadCloser to it's original state
response.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(rawBody))
```

Answer (score 8):

When you call `ReadAll` it's going to empty the buffer, so the second call will always return nothing. What you could do is save the result of `ReadAll` and reuse that in your functions. For example:

```
bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r);
log.Println(string(bytes))
```

Comment: A bad method if the reader contains VERY LARGE data, such as 2G byes.

Comment: As the name says, it's "ReadAll" so indeed you need to make sure you don't run out of memory. In many cases ReadAll is fine - no need for the complexity of streams if you only have a few MBs to read for example

Answer (score 1):

Technically, on one reader, you cannot read multiple times.

- Even if you create different references **but**
- when you read once it will be same object referred by all references.
- so what you can do is read the content and store it in one variable.
- Then use that variable as many times as you want.

This will print twice.

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    r := strings.NewReader("some io.Reader stream to be read\n")
    stringData, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r)
    log.Println(stringData)
    log.Println(stringData)
}
```

Comment: I want to know the reason why not :-)

Comment: @AbhishekSoni: An `io.Reader` is a stream. Once you finish the stream, there is no more. If you read part of the stream, the next read continues where you left off.

Answer (score -1):

Clone the `Reader` struct.

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    r := strings.NewReader("some io.Reader stream to be read\n")
    v := new(strings.Reader)
    *v = *r
    log.Println(ioutil.ReadAll(r))
    log.Println(ioutil.ReadAll(v))

}
```