# image.Decode returns error when decoding .png file

Tags: go

It seems that image.Decode (line 24) is returning an error when decoding the image. The image "test2.png" exists in the directory of the file, and is a function PNG image. For reference, this code is supposed to create a new image of the same resolution filled with one color randomly selected from test2.png. Any help here would be appreciated.

The code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image"
    "image/color"
    _ "image/jpeg"
    "image/png"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("test2.png")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("0 ", err)
        return
    }
    imageInConfig, _, err := image.DecodeConfig(file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("1 ", err)
        return
    }
    imageIn, fileType, err := image.Decode(file)
    fmt.Println("File type: ", fileType)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("2 ", err)
        return
    }

    outputWidth := imageInConfig.Width
    outputHeight := imageInConfig.Height
    imageOut := image.NewRGBA(image.Rectangle{image.Point{0, 0}, image.Point{outputWidth, outputHeight}})

    r, g, b, a := imageIn.At(int(rand.Intn(imageInConfig.Width)), int(rand.Intn(imageInConfig.Height))).RGBA()
    pixelColor := color.RGBA{uint8(r), uint8(g), uint8(b), uint8(a)}

    for x := 0; x < outputWidth; x++ {
        for y := 0; y < outputHeight; y++ {
            imageOut.Set(x, y, pixelColor)
        }
    }

    fileCreated, _ := os.Create("test2out.png")
    png.Encode(fileCreated, imageOut)
}
```

The error outputted is:

```
image: unknown format
```

Comment: You are ignoring errors. Do not ignore them, and they should tell what's wrong.

Comment: I just changed this; it turns out image.Decode was returning an error (image: unknown format). All the posts I've seen about this say to simply import "image/png", but I already did.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to read from the same io.reader(file) twice. The first time in

```
image.DecodeConfig(file)
```

and the second time in

```
image.Decode(file)
```

The second time you try to read from the same io.reader, you will get EOF

> When Read encounters an error or end-of-file condition after successfully reading n > 0 bytes, it returns the number of bytes read. It may return the (non-nil) error from the same call or return the error (and n == 0) from a subsequent call. An instance of this general case is that a Reader returning a non-zero number of bytes at the end of the input stream may return either err == EOF or err == nil. The next Read should return 0, EOF.

Read more about it here https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader

Something quick and simple you can do is to open the file twice

```
file, err := os.Open("test2.png")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("0 ", err)
    return
}
imageInConfig, _, err := image.DecodeConfig(file)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("1 ", err)
    return
}

file2, err := os.Open("test2.png")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("3 ", err)
    return
}
imageIn, _, err := image.Decode(file2)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("4 ", err)
    return
}
```

Alternatively, you can try reading multiple times from the same file.
[How to read multiple times from same io.Reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791021/how-to-read-multiple-times-from-same-io-reader)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make this call between these lines `image.DecodeConfig(file)` and `image.Decode(file)`:

```
file.Seek(0, io.SeekStart)
```