# how to get total row num in csv file

Tags: csv, go

I would like to get total row num first, if num meets need, will parse file from beginning, but I have known above code sample will get number but cursor is at the end of file. how to handle it?

```
reader := csv.NewReader(fs)
reader.ReadAll()
```

except for above way, can also provide other ways to get total rows if have

Comment: The `TeeReader` should work for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791021/how-to-read-multiple-times-from-same-io-reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180.html) which is implemented by [csv package](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/csv) does not define any metadata which would keep track of total rows. Of course some applications may store such metadata but in such case you would need a custom parser for reading them.